# How to ignore creating tables if existing in Postgresql database with eclipselink?

Tags: postgresql, jpa, persistence, eclipselink, postgresql-8.4

I'm using a Postgresql database with eclipselink2.3 provider in JOnAS (Java environment). My configuration is :

persistence.xml:

```
...
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>
<property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="POSTGRESQL"/>
...
```

Postgresql version is

```
Version : 8.4.11-0squeeze1
```

JDBC driver version is

```
postgresql-8.4-703.jdbc3.jar
```

When database is empty, there is no problem.

My problem is when eclipselink.ddl-generation is set to create-tables and tables are already existing in data base, an error is occured and process doesn't not continue with the next statement as explained [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Extensions_%28ELUG%29#eclipselink.ddl-generation).

Does anyone see a solution for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any [property](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/connect.html) that would prevent throwin error in your case. So i would suggest the following. You should have 3 persistence.xml files for 3 different environoments: development, testing and production.

In development environoment you want to work with clean database, so

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
```

The same with testing environoment, but in this case I would use DBUnit to fill database with test data.

In production you don't want to mess with database structure so

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="none"/>
```

is the right choice.

If you use ant or maven such configuration is fairly easy to accomplish (you might find examples in the net, since this is pretty standard approach).

I guess you will not like this answer ;), since this looks like quite a lot of additional work, but in the long run clean configuration and separation would pay off.

Comment: In fact, database is created and configured upstream. So, I set the property to none.

Answer (score 0):

The "create-tables" option does not fail if the table already exists.  It will log the error, but continue.
If you don't want to see the error, you can turn off logging.

What error do you get?